# CSP Errors on all browsers except chrome-based ones with styled-components

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, styled-components, content-security-policy

I am receiving the following errors on Firefox, Safari, IE11 and older versions of Edge.

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). 2 36bedd2677c04ba9cb34.js:5084:96245

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).

Error: An error occurred. See https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/packages/styled-components/src/utils/errors.md#10 for more information.
```

Everything works on all browsers when run on localhost but when released it throws the above errors.

The styled-component error refers to there being more than one version of styled-components installed. I confirmed that all versions are the same and they are all managed by lerna. I also tried only installing one top level version of the package but that did not solve anything either.

The CSP policies are as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https:; style-src 'none'; style-src-elem 'unsafe-inline' https:;">
```

Given that these are the policies, shouldn't the site always work? It requires unsafe-inline because of `styled-components`.

There is also a tiny amount of inline code/styles within the html file used to run the react-app.

Comment: Not really an answer, but: Chrome Rules!  When I write code I write it for and test it on Chrome only.  If someone says: "but I'm using ie!" (for example), I answer: "Why?" and "Chrome Rules!"... :)  You can run a browser detection that if is not Chrome says: "Switch to the only browser: Chrome"... :)  I'm sure you HAVE TO make it work for "other" browsers - thought you'd get a laugh from my comment...

Comment: I agree with the above. The intention is to show a message to use a better browser if the browser is compatible but at a minimum, firefox should work, Edge does (cause it is now built on chromium) and safari unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `style-src-elem` does not work on non-chrome browsers as of now.

As a result, the fallback was `style-src 'none'` which is the most restrictive option.

The solution was `style-src 'unsafe-inline'`

Comment: Note that using `style-src 'unsafe-inline'` has security implications, as the value suggests.

Comment: The issue was the need to run an inline script that runs before any of the site loads due to incompatibility issues on very old browsers